# Cannot run R in jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rstudio

I wanted to ask how to repair kernel connection for R in jupyter notebook,

I am able to run R in Rstudio and python in jupyter notebook, I used to write R in jupyter notebook but after some updates(I dont know what updates) R stop working in jupyter notebook.

I would like to ask for some advices - I would like to run it without reinstalling it

I also folled some question on stackoverflow and on google but it was not helpfull.

I attached images of what errors it returns[image][image]

I did try: `$ conda install -c r r-irkernel`